# Поворот 2D персонажа, с помощью бросания луча

Tags: unity3d

сижу над данной проблемой уже 2-й день и ничего не могу сделать. Пробовал писать скрипт и так и сяк и все ровно не могу добиться желаемого результата, а именно поворот персонажа на 180 градусов с помощью бросания луча. Суть в том, что мне нужно чтобы персонаж поворачивался на 180 градусов если дистанция между персонажем, который его бросает и твердым объектом меньше либо ровно 1. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема. Может я не правильно луч бросаю или не ту проверку делаю. Вот скрипт:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты ради прикола писани в лог точку куда он уперается `ray.point` с визуализацией (скажем тестовый cube следит за ней) и дистанцию... Искать баги и косяки на кофейной гуще очень весело, но не совсем эффективно.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо ты хочешь сделать врага на манер гриба из Марио который будет ходить туда сюда между двумя стенками.

Проблема в том что `ray.distance` равен 0 если луч ничего не нашел. Поэтому лучше сперва проверить `ray.collider != null`.

Стоит не забыть у стенки добавить компонент типа BoxColider2D. Также обрати внимание что `transform.forward`это синяя ось объекта(в 2D режиме её не видно), она смотрит в сторону камеры. И код поворота сработает только когда персонаж наполовину зайдет под стенку до своего центральной точки(пивота).

Вот пример работающего кода

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //transform.localPosition = transform.localPosition + Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed * transform.right;
        transform.Translate(speed *Time.fixedDeltaTime,0,0);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            if (hit.distance < 1)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles +=   new Vector3(0,180,0);
                Debug.Log("Препятствие " + hit.collider+" "+ hit.distance );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: это не помогло, результат абсолютно такой-же как и до вашего ответа.

Comment: @ilya выложил содержимое папки Asset. Попробуй запустить мою карту. [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zwTqNMO8jmCGAv7jgWcGTdRfLi8A8Fs3)